# Nginx 2 webservers behind 1 IP

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 2 web servers plus the nginx server as a reverse proxy.  call them web1 web2 and nginx1.

- web1   10.0.0.110 with abc.com, def.com
- web2   10.0.0.120 with hij.com, klm.com
- nginx1 10.0.0.125

Im trying to have 2 webservers behind 1 external IP

I have nothing in /etc/nginx/conf.d/
I have created conf files for each site in sites-available and linked them with symlinks to sites-enabled.

example file.

```
server {
           listen 80;
           server_name *.abc.com;
           access_log off;
           error_log off;
           location / {
              proxy_pass http://10.0.0.110/;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
              client_max_body_size 10m;
              client_body_buffer_size 128k;
              proxy_connect_timeout 90;
              proxy_send_timeout 90;
              proxy_read_timeout 90;
              proxy_buffer_size 4k;
              proxy_buffers 4 32k;
              proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
              proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
           }


}
```

The problem is its not working correctly, it seems to want to direct all the sites to either server, it seems to be dependent on the last conf file I edit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide a server directive per backend webserver. Here's an example of what should work for you (replacing the ellipsis with your additions):

```
server {
  server_name abc.com def.com;
  ...
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.110/;
    ...
  }
}

server {
  server_name hij.com klm.com;
  ...
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.120/;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that do the same thing? Would I need to put 

upstream web1 {

    server 10.0.0.110;

}

upstream web2 {

   server 10.0.0.120;

}
which file do I put this code in?

Comment: ah, i missed the two separate domain part of your question. you're actually looking to have nginx host multiple unique domains on each of these web servers as opposed to having nginx load balance between 2 web servers? you'll need two separate server { ... } directives. you can also add multiple domains by providing a list of domains separated by spaces for the server_name directive. you won't need a upstream directives if there's only 1 web server behind each of the domains.

Comment: Yeah I believe thats what I have but instead of using 1 config file for all the websites I have 1 config file for each website So each website has a file like abc.com.conf def.com.conf in  /sites-available then I created a symlink to /sites-enabled and then I have incude /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf in my nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have it sorted, i needed to have the IP set

```
listen 10.0.0.125:80
```

And set the domain name correctly *.abc.com doesn't include abc.com, it only included all the subdomains.

so I changed it to

```
server_name .abc.com;
```

Just making one of these changes didn't solve my problem.